# Why am I having error during installation of php on rhel 8

Tags: php

I got the error below when I run `sudo dnf module enable php:remi-7.4`

Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'remi-modular':

- Status code: 403 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/modular/aarch64/mirror (IP: 176.31.103.194)
- Status code: 403 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/modular/aarch64/mirror (IP: 109.238.14.107)
  Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'remi-modular': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Status code: 403 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/modular/aarch64/mirror (IP: 176.31.103.194)

I was trying to install php

Comment: If you click any of this links, you will get an explanation: "Only mirrorlist are served.". Try to add different mirror repo from [here](https://rpms.remirepo.net/)

Comment: Remi repository for aarch64 is only available for EL-9
See https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/214

Comment: Also https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Also https://twitter.com/RemiRepository/status/1658716410619613184